# Can I (almost) always transform a nonliear system of ODEs to a conditionally linear one, at least numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, numerical-calculus

There are some methods for solving a class of non-linear systems, so-called conditionally linear which [posit the following form](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/18M123390X):

$$\dot y_i = a(y_{\sim i}) y_i +b(y_{\sim i})\hspace{1cm} \forall i={1,...,d}$$

for the $i$th component of a a $d$-dimensional system. The key here is that the system can be written in a linear form if the non-lienar functions $a$ and $b$ are only functions of components $j \ne i$ (denoted by $\sim i$ here).

It seems to me that, at least in a large range of problems, it is possible to separate a linear term from the non-linear functions treat the system as if it was conditionally linear. For instance, consider

$$\dot x = xy \sin(-y)$$
$$\dot y = y^3 \exp(-x)$$

which can be cast as

$$\dot x =x \times F(y)$$
$$\dot y =y \times G(x,y)$$

with

$$F(y) = y\sin(-y)$$
$$G(x,y) = y^2\exp(-x)$$

Clearly, while $F$ is $x$-independent, $G$ is not $y$-independent. So strickly speaking, the system is not conditionally linear. However, there are numerical methods that treat this system like so, by using implicit-explicit methods. For instance, one can numerically construct the rates at time step $n$, by using the values of $(x,y)$ at the previous time steps (explicit):

$$\dot x_n =x_n \times F(y_{n-1})$$
$$\dot y_n =y_n \times G(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})$$

and solve the system above using an implicit technique. In this numerical setting, the system *looks like* a conditionally linear system, although the continuous one is not.

**My question is whether the discretized system is a conditionally linear one. And if so, can I use numerical methods such as [exponential Euler](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/120883657), as suggested by [Mascagni & Sherman](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Emascagni/papers/RCEV1996_1.pdf) and get the same convergence rate?**

Comment: Does $y$ have one dimension in $\dot y = y^3 \exp(-y/y_0)$ ? If the answer is yes: Is $z$ independent of $y$ ? If the answer to that is yes: can the "system" be possibly conditionally linear ?

Comment: @KurtG.You have a point. I edited my question.